# What is the Japanese word for video views on the Internet?

Tags: word-requests, english-to-japanese, internet-slang

For videos on the Internet like YouTube, which have a specific number of the times they've been viewed by people. What are those views called in Japanese?

Answer (score 10):

How about 「[視聴]{しちょう}[回数]{かいすう}」?

[image]

I think [再生]{さいせい}回数 would also work.

Comment: For what it's worth, 再生数 was used in Love Live! anime for a number of views of an internet video 「すごい再生数ですね」. I'm not sure if there's a difference in formality or nuance

Comment: @NoxArt 再生回数、再生数、閲覧回数、閲覧数... どれもよいと思います。formality の違いは、特に感じません。

Answer (score 5):

> What are those views called in japanese?

閲覧{えつらん}回数{かいすう} or 閲覧{えつらん}数{すう}

Pikotaro's PPAP dance was viewed more than 200 million times.

> ピコ太郎{たろう}のPPAPダンスは２億{おく}回{かい} 以上{いじょう} 閲覧{えつらん}された。  　
>   ピコ太郎{たろう}のPPAPダンスの閲覧{えつらん} 回数{かいすう}は２億回{おくかい}を超{こ}えた。

Though 「閲覧回数」is a general term, if you limit the term to a video viewing, 「再生回数」is often used.

**About 「閲覧｛えつらん｝回数｛かいすう｝/閲覧｛えつらん｝数｛すう｝」 and 「再生｛さいせい｝回数｛かいすう｝/再生｛さいせい｝数｛すう｝」**

In this topic, the meaning of "閲覧｛えつらん｝" is to look at or read contents. There are various forms of contents, such as articles, drawings, photographs, videos, and so on. Among these contents, all of them besides videos could be looked at or read by accessing the accommodated screen. So the number of 「閲覧｛えつらん｝」 increases by one if you access the page. However, as for video viewings the number of 「閲覧｛えつらん｝」 does not increase only by accessing the page where the videos are contained, because in order to watch them you have to click the "replay" button. The term for "replay" in Japanese is 「再生｛さいせい｝」. Therefore the term 「再生｛さいせい｝ 回数｛かいすう｝/再生｛さいせい｝数｛すう｝」 exists particularly to express the number of video views.

Comment: Just on the off chance that someone wants to use these terms for a kind of interface which may be seen by both Chinese and Japanese speakers, it is perhaps worth mentioning that 再生, which means ‘replay’ in Japanese, means ‘rebirth’ or even ‘reincarnation’ in Chinese. So 再生回数 to a Chinese reader will almost certainly be understood as “number of times you’ve been reborn”, which could potentially lead to some rather perplexed viewers. This is not an issue if it’s only intended for Japanese viewers, of course.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm sure Google was aware of this and therefore chose the more universally understood 視聴 for YouTube, but as long as we can trust them with their view counts, [再生 is overwhelmingly the most popular word out of these used with 回数](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E5%9B%9E%E6%95%B0,%E8%A6%96%E8%81%B4%E5%9B%9E%E6%95%B0,%E9%96%B2%E8%A6%A7%E5%9B%9E%E6%95%B0). According to a dictionary, 再生 can mean rebirth even in Japanese, but I don't think they account for much of the graph. Still a good point because this answer is already very detailed.

Comment: Thank you Janus Bahs Jacquet and Siikamiika for your comment on the word 「再生」. Actually a "play" button not a "replay" button in English is the equivalent word for  「再生」ボタン in Japanese. If I edit "replay" to "play" in my Answer, unexpected confusion may occur, so I will not edit the wording as a white lie.

Comment: @mackygoo I don't know about the etymology of 再生 as a video view, but it could also be understood as "bringing the filmed scene back to life" in addition to "replaying the video"

Answer (score 3):

ニコニコ動画 calls them 再生{さいせい}:

[image]

I'm sure there are many other ways to say it, though.

Answer (score 0):

shichou 視聴
shichousha are viewers